# Are there any good polling strategies to use with Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, long-polling, integration-patterns

I'm new to Apache Camel and currently reading Camel in Action. I'm building a system that will receive json messages via restful webservices and I plan to turn them into acsii files and transmit them to another system via SFTP. 
The problem is the response file will take over 10 minutes to return per request so I need to come up with a polling/monitoring strategy that will keep track of the request state.

Can anyone point me in the right direction if there is a specific EIP that handles this sort of problem?

Comment: Isn't this just about setting a high enough timeout ?

Comment: As I understand it, Camel will pause until that thread executes. So if I'm executing multiple requests I don't think a long timeout will be efficient enough. I think I need to continually check against some DB stored request/response ID